# Using a Java Scanner to read multiple patterns for the same object

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to read in parameters for an object class from a text file. The class only requires one parameter int id. The remaining three parameters are optional and are determined by the object constructor if not provided.

The text files are generated in the following format:

```
`R|G id [volume] [hasESP] [isVegetarian]
int id, int volume, boolean hasESP, boolean isVegitarian
```

Example:

```
R 33
R 423 16 t f
G 77 8 f t
R 33 t f
G 88
```

Here is my current code to read files of this format:

```
    private void readMartianFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner martian = new Scanner(file);
    char type = martian.next().charAt(0);
    int newId ;
    int newVol;
    char esp;
    char veg;


    while(martian.hasNext()) {
        type = martian.next().charAt(0);
        switch(type) {
        case 'G':

            break;
        case 'R':
            break;
        }

    }
    martian.close();
}
```

I can get it to here switching between which constructor to use but I cannot figure out how to find the pattern of the input and use it accordingly so I do not get RunTime errors or InvalidArgument errors. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `R|G id [volume] [hasESP [isVegetarian]]`? Otherwise you cannot tell `R|G id hasESP` appart from `R|G id isVegetarian`.

Answer (score 0):

With builder pattern, you could do it with ease. The code example contains some lambda. If you are using < jdk8, you can convert that lambda to the regular method.

```
class Martian {

private String type;
private int id;
private int volume;
private boolean hasESP;
private boolean isVegitarian;

public Martian(String type, int id, int volume, boolean hasESP,
    boolean isVegitarian) {
    this.type = type;
    this.id = id;
    this.volume = volume;
    this.hasESP = hasESP;
    this.isVegitarian = isVegitarian;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public int getVolume() {
    return volume;
}

public boolean isHasESP() {
    return hasESP;
}

public boolean isVegitarian() {
    return isVegitarian;
}

public static MartianBuilder builder() {
    return new MartianBuilder();
}

static class MartianBuilder {

    private String type;
    private int id;
    private int volume;
    private boolean hasESP;
    private boolean isVegitarian;

    public MartianBuilder type(String type) {
        this.type = type;
        return this;
    }

    public MartianBuilder id(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public MartianBuilder volume(int volume) {
        this.volume = volume;
        return this;
    }

    public MartianBuilder hasESP(boolean hasESP) {
        this.hasESP = hasESP;
        return this;
    }

    public MartianBuilder vegitarian(boolean vegitarian) {
        isVegitarian = vegitarian;
        return this;
    }

    public Martian build() {
        return new Martian(type, id, volume, hasESP, isVegitarian);
    }
}
```

This is how you can use above builder

```
public class MartianExample {

void readMartianFile(File file) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] split = line.split(" ");
        Martian martian = createMartian(split);
        // Decide what to do with read data
    }
}

private Martian createMartian(String[] rawData) {
    MartianBuilder builder = Martian.builder();
    int counter = 0;
    // read type
    counter = readData(builder::type, counter, rawData);

    // read id
    counter = readData((idString) -> builder.id(Integer.parseInt(idString)), counter,
        rawData);

    // read volume
    counter = readData((volumeString) -> builder.volume(Integer.parseInt(volumeString)),
        counter, rawData);

    // read hasESP
    counter = readData((hasESPString) -> builder.hasESP(Boolean.parseBoolean(hasESPString)),
        counter, rawData);

    // read isVegitarian
    counter = readData((isVegitarianString) -> builder.vegitarian(Boolean.parseBoolean
        (isVegitarianString)), counter, rawData);

    return builder.build();
}

private int readData(Consumer<String> consumer, int counter, String[] rawData) {
    if (counter < rawData.length) {
        consumer.accept(rawData[counter]);
        counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}
```